# Perl: Bareword found where operator expected at

Tags: perl, sh, bareword

I am trying to use perl to replace a string like so:

```
perl -pe "s/FlDigVal/$DIGN/" Header.xml > $DDIRP/$FNAME.xml
```

If `DIGN=+q4T/h/B8Saf0im3LtBevNvMPsd1PRG5Tz+Iq/uwjXA=` i get the following syntax error:

```
Having no space between pattern and following word is deprecated at -e line 1.
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "s/FlDigVal/+q4T/h"
Having no space between pattern and following word is deprecated at -e line 1.
syntax error at -e line 1, near "s/FlDigVal/+q4T/h"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I guess this is related to `/h`being in variable DIGN. Is there a way to escape those reserved words?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use shell variables, which are just non-hygienic macros. Export the variable to Perl's environment:

```
DIGN=$DIGN perl -pe 's/FlDigVal/$ENV{DIGN}/'
```

Note the single quotes: we don't want the shell to change the Perl commands.

or pass the value as an argument:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { $replace = shift } s/FlDigVal/$replace/' "$DIGN" Header.xml
```

Nevertheless, you seem to be editing an XML document with regular expressions. It's a painful way, there are libraries like [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML) that handle XML correctly. E.g. what would happen if DIGN contained `&` or `<`?

Comment: Hi again @choroba, can you, please, give an example how to use LibXML to do this replacement? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @MihaiDumitru: Without seeing a sample of the input XML, I can't but guess.

Comment: What if there are more than one variable to be exported and replaced? Is there a way to escape $ if it is present in another variable? I do not know if escaping $ works with single quotes.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with reserved words but `/`.

If `DIGN` contains `+q4T/h/B8Saf0im3LtBevNvMPsd1PRG5Tz+Iq/uwjXA=`, your command passes the following code to perl:

```
s/FlDigVal/+q4T/h/B8Saf0im3LtBevNvMPsd1PRG5Tz+Iq/uwjXA=/
```

Here `s/FlDigVal/+q4T/` parses as a substitution command, but the rest is garbage.

The solution is to not let the shell interpolate variables into code. Instead you can pass strings via the environment:

```
DIGN="$DIGN" perl -pe 's/FlDigVal/$ENV{DIGN}/' Header.xml
```

(If `DIGN` is already exported, you don't need the `DIGN="$DIGN"` part.)

Here we use single quotes (no shell interpolation) and let perl grab a value from the environment.

Comment: Hi @melpomene, thank you for your comment. Actually the my entire command is `/usr/bin/perl -pe 's/RBIRef/${REF//$/\\$}/;s/MsgIdtf/$MSGIF/;s/FlDigVal/$ENV{DIGN}/;s/filename/$FNAME/' Header.xml > $DDIRP/$FNAME.xml`, using single quoutes gives me another error `Backslash found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "$/\"
        (Missing operator before \?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near "$/\"
Missing right curly or square bracket at -e line 1, at end of line
syntax error at -e line 1, at EOF
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
`. I guess this due to escaping `$`

Comment: @MihaiDumitru What is `${REF//$/\\$}` supposed to do? If you're just trying to escape `$` for use in perl code, don't: Pass in `REF`, `MSGIF`, `DIGN`, `FNAME` via the environment and let perl fetch the values. Then there's no need to escape anything.

Comment: $REF is another variable which contains $ in it. I was using `${REF//$/\\$}` to pass `$`, so using single quotes breaks this replacement.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer.